# Rails query which record's number range a value falls into

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that stores a lower and upper limit value in each record. The values do not overlap.

Given a number, how do I query the records to see what record contains the range that the number falls into?

I think I could do something like below but I'm wondering is there a cleaner and more efficient answer

```
@records.each do |r|
    if number.between?(r.lower_value, r.upper_value)
        desired_record = r.id
        break
    end 
end
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You can write arel or SQL in your activerecord finders. Something like @records.each { |record| record.where('lower_value IS ? AND upper_value IS ?', number, number).first }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a `Range` and test inclusion of the number with `include?`.

```
@records.each do |r|
  if (r.lower_value..r.upper_value).include?(number)
    desired_record = r.id
    break
  end 
end
```

If you want to get all records where number is within range:

```
@records.select {|r| (r.lower_value..r.upper_value).include?(number)}
```

If you just want the first record:

```
@records.detect {|r| (r.lower_value..r.upper_value).include?(number)}
```

If you want to pull only the matching records out of the database:

```
Model.where("lower_value <= ? AND upper_value >= ?", number, number)
```

Comment: Thanks. The last statement you gave is what I'm looking for. Really should have known it myself.

Comment: Hi infused, I've encountered another issue when searching the range. Is there a way to store a value for infinity as one of the records does not hold an upper value (because it's infinity). I've been googling for hours but don't know how to incorporate the case where one record has no upper value into my query above

Comment: I just updated my answer with how to handle that case.

Comment: Actually, will that always return the record where the upper value is null? There will only be one with an upper value of null (the last one) but that query will always return it because it will always satisfy the condition. I only want one record returned at any one time

Comment: No problem. I've kind of figured it out. I run the original query and if it doesn't return anything I take the last record as that's the one with no upper limit. A hack, but it works. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

how about using `between` if your database supports it?

`Record.find_by_sql("SELECT * from records where ? BETWEEN lower_value and upper_value", number)`

and let the database do the work.

Example in postgresql:

```
foo_development=# select * from records;
 id | lower_value | upper_value
----+-------------+-------------
  1 |           1 |          10
  2 |          11 |          15
  3 |          16 |         120
(3 rows)


 select * from records where 100 between lower_value and upper_value;
 id | lower_value | upper_value
----+-------------+-------------
  3 |          16 |         120
(1 row)
```